# Can't download php_mongodb.dll from pecl website

Tags: php, mongodb, driver, pecl

I'm trying to install the php mongodb driver. I've set up my php.ini file and now, I want to download the php_mongodb.dll so that I can put it inside php/ext/. However, I cannot find the link where I can download the DLL of the php mongodb driver. It's driving me crazy because all the tutorials I've seen casually say :

*"Now, go to https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb and download the DLL".*

However, I cant see where is the link...

What I see on my screen : 
[image]

Also, I found a youtube video where I can clearly see the button to download the DLL, but on my side, there is NOTHING. (https://youtu.be/9gEPiIoAHo8?t=91)

[image]

Where can I download the DLL if its no longer available on PECL website ?

**EDIT :**

The DLL icon is back on the PECL website : https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb
I'm glad I took a screenshot to testify that I was not crazy !

Comment: Is this any good for you https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl

Comment: sorry but, where can I find the php_mongodb.dll that I need in all this ? I dont think what you shared contains my DLL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a link to the list of various releases of the driver:

https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongodb/

Not sure what they did to the website to remove the links to the windows downloads though..

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing in September 2023, PHP have not hosted up to date downloads of the windows MongoDB driver since mid 2021.

You can instead find current releases for windows targets at [the official MongoDB GitHub org](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases), as well as installation and update instructions for other platforms.